# Syntax error or access violation on PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I need some assitance on PDO. I've created a little wrapper to extend `PDO` functionality, the class is very simple, I want focus the attention on the `select` method, this working for simple query, but if I insert `JOIN` in it seems that `PDO` will fail to perform the statement. This is the method:

```
public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $sth = $this->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);
    }

    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetchAll($fetchMode);
}
```

Now in the constructor I've enabled the exception as:

```
public function __construct($DB_TYPE, $DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS)
{
    parent::__construct($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

I saved this `PDO` wrapper inside the `db` property, so I can call the `select` function as: `$this->db`, check the interested query:

```
$userData = $this->db->select('SELECT id as user_id, email as user_email, role as role_slug
                                   FROM users
                                   INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.role
                                   INNER JOIN user_settings ON user_settings.id_user = user.id
                                   WHERE company = :company, username = :username, password = :password',
                                    array(':company' => $company, ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
```

How you can see I'm trying to select the `id, email, role` of the user on he table `users`, I need also to get the role on the other table called `roles` and the user setting on the table `user_settings`. Now the `username` is on the table called `user_settings`, for a complete structure:

**users**

```
id|id_company|first_name|last_name|email|mobile_phone
```

**user_settings**

```
id_user|username|password
```

**roles**

```
id|name
```

I really don't know what does this error means. Anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, and sorry for any errors, I'm new on this site.

Comment: what is the error and error code.....

Comment: You are not using the `WHERE` clause correctly. The syntax is `WHERE col_1 = 'x' AND|OR col_2 = 'xy'` etc. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: @NDM Sorry I miss to add this in the question.

Comment: If your custom class extends PDO, `$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` should throw a `PDOException` on SQL syntax error. If it doesn't, that means that you haven't configured your PHP development box to display error messages and you absolutely need to address that first, rather than just guess all the time.

Comment: answer given below (and a comment on "how" to use a WHERE clause) yet.... nothing from the OP. I'm out.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you mean error handler? I enabled the php error unfortunately seems that isn't displayed :\

Comment: Exceptions work in PHP. Perhaps you didn't it the right way.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I build my own mvc framework but I didn't find a good article that explain error handler

Comment: In that case, you might have written a custom exception handler that catches the exception and won't allow you to see it. PHP error handler works fine out of the box but there're many ways to mess with it (I'm some times guilty too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE company = :company, username = :username, password = :password
```

is incorrect, you can't use `,` to separate conditions, use `AND` or `OR`

```
WHERE company = :company AND username = :username AND password = :password
```